# capturing performance of a remote linux server?

Tags: python, linux, performance, automation

I want to capture performance( CPU and Memory Usage) of a remote linux server something like output of TOP command in terminal time to time and import it to a excel file on my local windows machine.
I am thinking of using python to connect to the server and executing the command and recording its output.
I am totally new to python, Please suggest some approach to this problem like from where should I start and all.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Python module "fabric" and then the fabric `run` function to capture the output of a command on the remote host.

It would look something like this:

```
import csv
from fabric.api import *

env.hosts = ['user@remotehost:22']
FILENAME = '/tmp/info.csv'


def get_info():
    output = run('top -bn 1')
    lines = output.splitlines()

    with open(FILENAME, 'wb') as csvfile:
        info = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for l in lines:
             info.writerow(l.split())
```

Then run this with: `fab get_info` from the script directory.

It will write a local csv-file from the output of "top" from the remote machine. The csv-file could then be opened from Excel. The csv file will look a little bit ugly for know. But it's all about changing the last line to something more intelligent.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`os.times`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.times)

```
>>> import os
>>> os.times()
(0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1361716040.0)
>>> help(os.times)
times() -> (utime, stime, cutime, cstime, elapsed_time)

Return a tuple of floating point numbers indicating process times.
```

.. and repeat calls to `os.times` for a given period at a given frequency to mimi `top`.

Piping this into an Excel document is less straightforward, but Excel can understand `csv`, comma separated variable files, so maybe something like

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os

with open('output.csv', 'w') as co:    
    for i in range(100):
        co.write('%s, %f,\n' % (datetime.now(), os.times()[0]))

    time.sleep(5)
```

This will open a file "`output.csv`", write the current time and cpu usage, wait 5 seconds and then repeat 100 times. The `csv` file can then be opened in Excel.

Example output:

```
2013-02-24 14:40:12.254806, 0.01,
2013-02-24 14:40:12.304922, 0.05,
2013-02-24 14:40:12.357945, 0.06,
2013-02-24 14:40:12.404362, 0.04,
```

To connect to the remote server, take a look at the Python `ssh2` module [`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

*Edit* as @[Christian Groleau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1157411/christian-groleau) mentioned, if you're going to be doing heavy lifting with `csv` files, take a look at the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) python module. [Someone](http://www.python-excel.org/) has even written some modules for directly reading / writing excel files (isn't python great?!)

Comment: Nice solution. You may also want to look into using the csv library's csv writer to create this output. If you're going to be manipulating data for Excel, learning this library will make your task easier in the long run.